# how do we pass the parameters to db via url in express js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to insert the value to db through html page & passing the value to url. But value has been inserted as null merely inserting the value from html page it's working but through url null value has been inserted.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var sql=require('mysql');
var createConnect=sql.createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"stud"
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    createConnect.getConnection(function(err,row){
        if(err) throw err;

        res.send("connected");
        console.log("connected");
    });
});



    app.use(express.static('public'));

    app.get('/index.html', function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"index.html");

    });

    app.get('/process1/:fname/:rno/:MobNO',function(req,res){
```

If I remove the `data1` value is inserted to db but I want to inset the data through url and html page also.

```
        var data1={
            sname:req.params.fname,
            regno:req.params.rno,
            mobno:req.params.MobNo
        };

        var data={
            sname:req.query.fname,
            regno:req.query.rno,
            mobno:req.query.MobNo
        };
        createConnect.query("INSERT INTO student set?",(data1,data), function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                console.log("check your query",err);
            }


                res.send("hello ram");
        });

    });
```